# How to find all jquery methods used in a javascript file using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This may be dumb idea but here is what I am trying to achieve. A project I am working on has a legacy front-end code. Site is super slow and one of the contributing factor is jQuery. My idea is to write a utility that will tell me all the jQuery functions that were used on the final build. So that I can build jQuery from the source and remove what is unnecessary.

I've tried closure compiler by google with no luck. Even tree-shaking resulted in broken code.

I don't know if this dumb but this is what I could think right off the bat. All criticism, solutions are welcome.

Comment: You need to make AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) from the code. Then it would be easier to search for the symbol and it's type. It's just an idea as I don't know enough to implement. Check out how it looks in https://astexplorer.net/ I got the link from article https://lihautan.com/manipulating-ast-with-javascript/

Comment: @ITgoldman Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just search file by file for any instance of "$(" ? This indicates something is jQuery.

Comment: No that would beat the whole purpose of trying to automate this. As the codebase I am searching within is thousands of lines and there are multiple files I need to search in. But thanks anyways for replying.